# Azure terratest - Build constraints exclude all Go files

Tags: azure, terratest

When I run pkg/mod/github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/test/azure  ...

`go test -v -run TerraformAzureKeyvaultExample`

I'm getting the following error:

> package github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/test/azure: build constraints exclude all Go files....

Has anyone else encountered this issue? How do I disable this so that I can actually run an Azure terratest?

-thai-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

accoding to [this issue][1] try using the *-tags azure* option like this:

```
go test -tags azure .
```

It worked for me.
[1]: https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/issues/557